# How to expose Corda service to RPC especially where JPA is used

Tags: corda

I am working on using JPA to map objects to off-ledger entries and had followed the example on https://github.com/corda/accounts where a corda service is created for class KeyManagementBackedAccountService and JPA with EntityManager used in fun accountInfo.

To use this service inside flows we invoke:

val FlowLogic<*>.accountService get() = serviceHub.cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService::class.java)

How do i re-use the same corda service (preferably something to similar to class KeyManagementBackedAccountService) and expose it to RPCOps, such that i can perform the same query through RPC like vaultQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your service query with some initiating flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class SomeFlow extends FlowLogic<SomeResponse> {

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SomeResponse call() throws FlowException {

         1) call to your service
         2) transform response if needed
         3) return response
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but yeah that would be trivial as its calling a flow. The idea to having something like vaultQuery() is that i don't need run queries through flow.